# Programmatically determine whether magick image has effects applied

Tags: r, imagemagick

Say you have an image file in R defined with `magick::image_read()`

```
library(magick)
frink <- image_read("https://jeroen.github.io/images/frink.png")
```

You can then apply an effect to negate the image colors

```
frink_neg <- image_negate(frink)
```

What I'd like to know is whether there is any attribute in the `frink_neg` object that says that this is an image that has had the negation effect applied to it. Something like

```
class(frink_neg) == 'image-negate'
```

I tried running

```
image_info(frink_neg)
image_attributes(frink_neg)
image_data(frink_neg)

str(frink_neg)
```

But none of these seem to give any info about applied effects. Is there any way I can query for this?
Ideally the solution would also work for any of the other filters supplied by `magick` (blur, charcoal, etc)

Comment: Nothing that I know will tell you if the image colors have been negated (inverted).

Comment: ImageMagick does not keep track of the operations applied to an image.

Comment: Thats a shame - thanks anyway